# How to extract value from an array of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of array stored. I need to extract the particular value from this arrays.

e.g allarray contain the list of arrays
allarray= [Array[3],Array[3],Array[3]] are three arrays present in that.

0:Array[3]
 0:"a1"
 1:"b1"
 2:"c1"

1:Array[3] 
 0:"a2"
 1:"b2"
 2:"c2"

3:Array[3] 
 0:"a3"
 1:"b3"
 2:"c3"

I need to extract this c1,c2 and c3 from the above arrays and display in the alert box.

Can anyone tell me how i can do that?

i tried with $.each but unfortunately doesn't work. Can anyone?

Comment: post a jsfiddle of what you have done so far

Comment: You need a loop within a loop.

Comment: You want usually get the 3rd element of each array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your array looks like this

```
var allarray = [["a1","b1","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"],["a3","b3","c3"]];
```

To get c1, c2, and c3 you could just do this

```
 var c1 = allarray[0][2], c2 = allarray[1][2], c3 = allarray[2][2];
```

or you could do a loop to put all of the cs in a single array of its own

```
var cs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < allarray.length; i++) {
  cs.push(allarray[i][2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var allarray = [
    ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
    ["a2", "b2", "c2"],
    ["a3", "b3", "c3"]
],
    num = 2;

//one by one
allarray.forEach(function( arr ) {
    alert( arr[ num ] );
});

//or all at once
alert( allarray.map(function( arr ) { return arr[ num ]; }).join(',') );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the Array.prototype.map function is for:

```
var arr = [["a1","b1","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"],["a3","b3","c3"]];

var theValues = arr.map(function(inner) {return inner[2]});

alert(theValues.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try using `map()`. Example:

```js
var allarray = [["a1","b1","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"],["a3","b3","c3"]],
    index = 2;
allarray.map(function(val, ind){
    document.write(allarray[ind][index] + '<br />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrOfArr=[['a1','b1','c1'],['a2','b2','c2'],['a3','b3','c3']];

var cVals=arrOfArr.map(function(element,index){
      return arrOfArr[index][2];
});
alert(cVals);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uaugbem/

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by running

```
allarray[X][2]
```

where X is 0, 1, or 2 depending on which of the 3 arrays you want